# Moving the point along projection of the edge

Tags: modeling

I wanted to move the point along projection of the edge onto XY plane. And I don't have any idea how to do this. One way is to move point with locked Z and snapping to the edge, but it has two serious problems: the target edge also will be moving and the snapping will be applying to the any edge of the underlied highpoly mesh (are there way to exclude this mesh from snapping I also don't know, I didn't found it).
So can anybody help me with this task? And yeah, sorry for my bad English...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a vertex, you want to move, in the course of normal editing? Do you need to do this repeatedly? What _end result_ are you looking for?

Comment: @Robin Betts yes, I need to do this operation repeatedly for every similar vertex on the mesh. The target is to move these vertices along "right" directions to underlied highpoly surface. As the result I need to get the low poly mesh wich covers the high poly mesh and has the good topology.

Comment: I found one way: it needs to move 3D-cursor to the target point and select the transformation center to it, select the current coord system to View, then select and duplicate the direction edge, scale copy along Z to zero, align view to this edge, move this edge sligthely along Y to have the possibility to select the target point again, select and move target point along Y (that is the required projection), finally delete the scaled copy of the edge. It works, but... Too many actions! And it need repeat for many vertices! Is there way more simple?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, a quite fast way to this move is:

- Set your Pivot to 'Active Element'
- Select your moving vertex, and then your static vertex, so static is active.
- use <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale the moving vertex to the static vertex in XY.

But a better way (among many) to retopologize, if that's what you are doing,  would be to construct your low-poly mesh edges in plan view, in a plane above the terrain, without regard to the height of the vertices.

Then when you are happy with the XY form, from top orthographic, set Snap to 'Face' and 'Project Individual Elements', and hit <kbd>G</kbd>. The entire low-poly surface will then snap down, conforming to the high-poly mesh below.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Your solution is much more better then my one))